# Use several columns values as input to a function to compute new column in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I am using *data.table* to process a dataset with a several columns. I need to use a few of those column values to compute a new column specific for each row. I know I can use the *SDcols* functionality for some simple functions. However, it's trickier when I want to use my own function, which treats the column values differently. Here is my example:

This is how the *data.table* looks like:

```
  Training Age  Client1 Stim1.0 Stim1.1  Client2 Stim2.0 Stim2.1 Choice Val.00 Val.01
1:        0   1  absence       0       0  absence       0       0      2      0      0
2:        0   2  absence       0       0  absence       0       0      2      0      0
3:        0   3 Object 1       1       1 Object 2       2       2      1      0      0
4:        0   4 Object 2       2       1 Object 2       2       1      1      0      0
5:        0   5  absence       0       0  absence       0       0      2      0      0
6:        0   6  absence       0       0  absence       0       0      2      0      0
   Val.02 alpha.0 Val.10 Val.11 Val.12 alpha.1 V25
1: 0.0000   0.005      0 0.0000 0.0000   0.005  NA
2: 0.0000   0.005      0 0.0000 0.0000   0.005  NA
3: 0.0025   0.005      0 0.0000 0.0025   0.005  NA
4: 0.0050   0.005      0 0.0025 0.0025   0.005  NA
5: 0.0050   0.005      0 0.0025 0.0025   0.005  NA
6: 0.0050   0.005      0 0.0025 0.0025   0.005  NA
```

The function uses the value of the columns starting with *Stim* to choose which of the columns starting with *Val* must be included in the computation of the new value.

When the number of *Stim* and *Val* columns is low, say 2 and 3 respectively, I can solve it using *fcase*

```
rawData[,`:=`(Val.Client1=fcase(Stim1.0==0,Val.00,
                               Stim1.0==1,Val.01,Stim1.0==2,Val.02)+
                fcase(Stim1.1==0,Val.10,
                      Stim1.1==1,Val.11,Stim1.1==2,Val.12),
              Val.Clien2=fcase(Stim2.0==0,Val.00,
                               Stim2.0==1,Val.01,Stim2.0==2,Val.02)+
                fcase(Stim2.1==0,Val.10,
                      Stim2.1==1,Val.11,Stim2.1==2,Val.12))]
```

However, the number of columns vary on different data set I am using. So, I'd like to code it independently of the number of columns.

I have managed to make it work using a combination of *.SDcols* and *apply* in this way:

```
numSti<-2,numFeat<-2 # parameters to know the number of columns to expect
rawData[,Val.Client1:=apply(.SD,MARGIN = 1,FUN = function(x){
# I use apply to get a vector with alll the relevant values
  x<-as.numeric(x) # for some reason I must force it to be numeric 
  Stim1.tmp<-x[1:numSti]+1 # Choose the relevant values for the Stim columns
  vals<-x[(numSti*2+1): (numSti*2+numSti*(1+numFeat))] # choose the relevant values for the Val columns
  locVal<-Stim1.tmp+(numFeat+1)*(0:(numSti-1)) # map the Stim to the Val columns
  return(sum(vals[locVal])) # sum over the chosen values. 
}),.SDcols=patterns("Stim.|Val.")]
```

This piece of code gives me the correct computation. But it's terribly slow!
Could you help me find a speedier solution?

By request of @jblood94:
The output of `dput(rawData)`

```
as.data.table(structure(list(Age = 1:6, Client1 = c(2L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 2L), 
    Stim1.0 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L), Stim1.1 = c(0L, 0L, 
    1L, 1L, 0L, 0L), Client2 = c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), Stim2.0 = c(0L, 
    0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L), Stim2.1 = c(0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L), 
    Choice = c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), Val.00 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0), Val.01 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Val.02 = c(0, 0, 0.0025, 
    0.005, 0.005, 0.005), alpha.0 = c(0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 
    0.005, 0.005), Val.10 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Val.11 = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0.0025, 0.0025, 0.0025), Val.12 = c(0, 0, 0.0025, 0.0025, 
    0.0025, 0.0025), alpha.1 = c(0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 
    0.005, 0.005), V25 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame")))
```

Comment: So if the table also had `Stim1.2` and `Stim2.2`, `numSti` should be 3? And if the values ranged from 0 to 4 (mapping to `Val.X0` though `Val.X4`), `numFeat` should be 4?

Comment: Should the `numStim` be 3, the *Stim* columns would be `Stim1.0`, `Stim1.1`, `Stim1.2`, `Stim1.3`. The first number indicates something else and is always 1 or 2. As for the *Val* columns and `numFeat`, you are correct.

Comment: Please post the output of `dput(rawData)`.

Comment: The pattern seems to be adding columns based on `Stim1.0` with columns based on `Stim1.1`, and repeat with basing columns `Stim2.0` and `Stim2.1`. Which columns are variant, the `Stim#.#` columns or the `Val.##` columns`?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this user function will help out:

```r
fun <- function(data, vals) {
  stimvals <- Map(function(V, levels) {
    match(paste0(sub("Stim[0-9]+\\.([0-9]+)", "Val.\\1", V), levels),
          names(data))
  }, setNames(nm = vals), lapply(vals, function(z) data[[z]]))
  Reduce(`+`, lapply(stimvals, function(z) as.data.frame(data)[cbind(seq_along(z), z)]))
}

stims <- grep("Stim.*", names(rawData), value = TRUE)
stims <- split(stims, sub("\\..*", "", stims))
names(stims) <- sub(".*([0-9]+)$", "Val.Client\\1", names(stims))
stims
# $Val.Client1
# [1] "Stim1.0" "Stim1.1"
# $Val.Client2
# [1] "Stim2.0" "Stim2.1"

rawData[, names(stims) := lapply(stims, fun, data = .SD)]
rawData
#      Age Client1 Stim1.0 Stim1.1 Client2 Stim2.0 Stim2.1 Choice Val.00 Val.01 Val.02 alpha.0 Val.10 Val.11 Val.12 alpha.1    V25 Val.Client1 Val.Client2
#    <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>  <int>  <num>  <num>  <num>   <num>  <num>  <num>  <num>   <num> <lgcl>       <num>       <num>
# 1:     1       2       0       0       2       0       0      2      0      0 0.0000   0.005      0 0.0000 0.0000   0.005     NA      0.0000      0.0000
# 2:     2       2       0       0       2       0       0      2      0      0 0.0000   0.005      0 0.0000 0.0000   0.005     NA      0.0000      0.0000
# 3:     3       0       1       1       1       2       2      1      0      0 0.0025   0.005      0 0.0000 0.0025   0.005     NA      0.0000      0.0050
# 4:     4       1       2       1       1       2       1      1      0      0 0.0050   0.005      0 0.0025 0.0025   0.005     NA      0.0075      0.0075
# 5:     5       2       0       0       2       0       0      2      0      0 0.0050   0.005      0 0.0025 0.0025   0.005     NA      0.0000      0.0000
# 6:     6       2       0       0       2       0       0      2      0      0 0.0050   0.005      0 0.0025 0.0025   0.005     NA      0.0000      0.0000
```

This is dynamically finding `Val*` names based on the `Stim*` sublevel (e.g., `.1` of `Stim2.1`) and the *values* in the corresponding `Stim2.1`. That is, if `Stim2.1` has a value of `0`, then it should pull from `Val.10`. The data is indexed based on the appropriate `Val*` columns and then assigned back into a name derived from the first number of the `Stim*` name (`2` of `Stim2.1`).

So the generation of the `stims` variable above is the key: group the corresponding `Stim#.#*` variables together (they will be subsetted/summed) and name them appropriately.

Comment: It works like a breeze! Thanks! I still need to look into it closely to fully understand. Perhaps one silly question. How come your console prints the date type for each column of the data.table? Mine doesn't, and it's really useful.

Comment: `options(datatable.print.class = TRUE)`, see `?data.table::print.data.table` for others.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be working. The idea is to index the `Val` columns based on the `Stim` values, put the result into an array of dimensions `c(nrow(rawData), numSti, 2)`, then permute the array in order to sum along the second dimension with `colSums`.

```
numSti <- 2
numFeat <- 2

rawData[
  ,paste0("Val.Client", 1:2) := as.data.table(
    colSums(
      aperm(
        array(
          unlist(rawData[,.SD , .SDcols = grep("Val.", names(rawData), value = TRUE)])[
            1:.N + (unlist(rawData[,.SD , .SDcols = grep("Stim", names(rawData), value = TRUE)]) + rep(c(0, numFeat + 1), each = .N))*.N
          ],
          c(.N, numSti, 2)
        ),
        c(2, 1, 3)
      )
    )
  )
]

rawData[, Val.Client1:Val.Client2]
#>    Val.Client1 Val.Client2
#> 1:      0.0000      0.0000
#> 2:      0.0000      0.0000
#> 3:      0.0000      0.0050
#> 4:      0.0075      0.0075
#> 5:      0.0000      0.0000
#> 6:      0.0000      0.0000
```

It can also be generalized for the number of clients:

```
numCli <- 2

rawData[
  ,paste0("Val.Client", 1:numCli) := as.data.table(
    colSums(
      aperm(
        array(
          unlist(rawData[,.SD , .SDcols = grep("Val.", names(rawData), value = TRUE)])[
            1:.N + (
              unlist(
                rawData[,.SD , .SDcols = grep("Stim", names(rawData), value = TRUE)]
              ) + rep(
                seq(0, by = numFeat + 1, length.out = numCli),
                each = .N
              )
            )*.N
          ],
          c(.N, numSti, numCli)
        ),
        c(2, 1, 3)
      )
    )
  )
]
```